# Banach space admitting a unique subsymmetric basis but not a symmetric one

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I have two quick questions:

It can be shown without too much trouble (using methods from Altshuler/Casazza/Lin, 1973) that any Lorentz sequence space admits a unique (up to equivalence) subsymmetric basis (which is also symmetric).

**Question 1.**  Are there any other known examples of a Banach space admitting a unique subsymmetric basis?

In 2004, Sari showed that the Tirilman spaces admit a subsymmetric basis but not a symmetric one.

**Question 2.** Are there any other known examples of a Banach space admitting a subsymmetric basis but not a symmetric basis?

I am especially interested in Banach spaces satisfying both properties simultaneously---that is, a Banach space admitting a unique subsymmetric basis which is not symmetric.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the literature on Schlumprecht's space?

Comment: @BillJohnson Yes I did, and I almost mentioned it above.  It was asked in the "Remarks" paper (Kutzarova/Lin, 1998) whether Schlumprecht space $S$ has a unique subsymmetric basis, but to my knowledge that question has never been answered.  Nor do I know whether it has ever been investigated to see if $S$ has a symmetric basis (which would give a negative answer to the uniqueness question).